# Calculate the absolute difference between the numbers in all rows for every possible pair of columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I would like to calculate the absolute difference between the numbers in every row for every possible pair of columns in a data frame.

For example with the following dataframe:

```
x <- rnorm(1:10)
y <- rnorm(1:10)
z <- rnorm(1:10)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
```

There are the possible column combinations of x-y, x-z, and y-z. I wish to calculate the difference of the numbers in each of the rows for each of the column pairs.

My desired output which would look something like this:

```
Variable 1  Variable 2  Difference
x   y   1
x   y   2
x   y   3
x   z   4
x   z   5
x   z   6
x   z   7
y   z   8
y   z   9
y   z   10
```

et cetera. I can currently calculate the mean difference between all of the numbers in the column pairs, but cannot work out how to reference the cells in the dataframe to give an output for each row. Here is the code I'm using for the mean difference.

```
combos <- combn(ncol(df),2)

adply(combos, 2, function(x) {
  mdiff <- (mean(df[, x[1]])) - (mean(df[, x[2]]))

  out <- data.frame("var1" = colnames(df)[x[1]]
                    , "var2" = colnames(df[x[2]])
                    ,  "diff" = sprintf("%.3f",mdiff)
  )
  return(out)

})
```

Any help getting the absolute difference between each row (e.g. x -y) for all the column pairs would be greatly appreciated.

Best,
Henry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the difference between the means of each row for the pair of columns,

```
combn(ncol(df),2, FUN = function(x) diff(rowMeans(df[x])))
```

and for difference between means of columns

```
combn(ncol(df),2, FUN = function(x) diff(colMeans(df[x])))
```

Based on the description in the OP's post, it could be also

```
combn(ncol(df),2, FUN = function(x) abs(df[,x[1]] - df[,x[2]]))
```